# Sharing QGIS projects containing PostGIS layers

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

How do we share QGIS projects that includes PostGIS data?  If I create a project loading PostGIS data with reader permissions, nobody can modify the data.  If saved layers had been loaded from PostGIS with an administrator or editor's credentials then anyone opening that project can modify the data.
We could create projects for individual users with PostGIS data loaded with that individual's credentials which would give the required permissions and protection but if we share that project with co-workers then they are effectively accessing the data via the first individual's credentials.
I'm sure others must have come up against this but I couldn't find a solution.
We are using QGIS 2.18, PostgreSQL 9.0.23 and PostGIS 1.5.

Comment: Please update the heading to something like Sharing read-only custom styled QGIS projects through PostgreSQL and or containing PostGIS layers.

Answer (score 3):

We use a generic 'reader' account rather than individual user accounts. This way they can be used to share QGIS projects with anyone who has that account set up on their QGIS instance.

The QGIS projects then reside on our shared network drive for anyone to use.

We also have an 'editor' account for those who are making data edits, and of course a 'dba'-type of account for the data owner.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This feels like a retrograde step compared to file managed approach where I could put say all planning data in a planning folder and create a workgroup for only planning officers to modify the shapefiles in that folder.  If I give Planning Officers access via a reader account they can't modify their own PostGIS data.  If I give them access via an editor account they could potentially edit another service's data.  Maybe we create editor accounts for each service and accept that we won't be able to track which individual has made a change?

Comment: We definitely don't have the editing workflows of your organization, but I would still recommend the use of generic accounts directed at workflows, rather than individual users. If you were interested in tracking, perhaps there is another layer that can be applied at the QGIS level that would allow a field to be auto-populated with the actual person who made the edit while under the EDITOR user account?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks DPSSpatial. We have decided to implement generic accounts for individual workflows supplying projects with data loaded using the service account and a PostGIS connection set up with the service account credentials to each team.